# Are there any differences in large or small pieces of root ginger?

Tags: indian-cuisine, fresh, ginger

I find the bigger ones easier to peel, but I've heard that, for example, in potatoes all the vitamins are just below the skin, so I wonder if by a similar effect, smaller rhizomes of root ginger would be more potent in flavour or aroma or different in some way?

Comment: Ben, welcome! One hint: Health questions are off topic, so I read your comparison to potatoes as "the aroma might be under the skin". If you would like to edit to clarify, this would perhaps even improve your question.

Comment: Stephie, Your interpretation of the question is correct, I am not specifically interested in vitamins, that was just used as an example.  I am specifically interested in any flavour differences, but I can't think of a better example than the potato.

Comment: would "how to maximize the content of (incidentally health related) compound X from ingredient Y when included in a dish" not be a technique rather than a health question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite the opposite, large ginger rhizomes are more potent both in flavour and aroma, because those compounds take time in the ground to develop and accumulate...

There's a Chinese proverb: "It's the older ginger that's got the punch /heat", referring to wisdom of the elders / the experienced...

The younger rhizomes have a milder flavour, and a smoother texture (the older ones are more fibrous) so are used for pickling in both Chinese and Japanese cuisines...